# Ubuntu 14.04 soft lockup on Vostro 3500

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from CD without third party package and without Internet connection on a Vostro 3500.

After installation and reboot, my machine is kind of frozen and when I switch to tty1 I see a bunch of

```
soft lockup cpu waits for ...
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

they work on it 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bugs?field.tag=apport-bug

"I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64 bit and my laptop (Dell XPS L702x using Nvidia Optimus) can't boot starting with kernel 3.13 (I've tried all three updates: 3.13.0-1-generic, 3.13.0-2-generic and 3.13.0-3-generic). When booting, I get this error: "BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s! [systemd-udevd:546]"

Booting the old 3.12 (3.12.0-8-generic) kernel works.

Here's the relevant part from syslog:...."

Comment: Same problem on a Macbook (also using Nvidia card) but I get the same bug even if I boot using an earlier kernel.  If I start up ubuntu in advanced mode I see the same "NMI handler took too long" message as here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/462174/unable-to-boot-following-update-to-trusty-get-nmi-handler-taking-too-long-mes

Comment: I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 13.04 from a LiveCD that I had used in the past (and worked).  After loading the LiveCD and getting the purple screen and keyboard/person icon, I get the same "soft lockup CPU#_ stuck for..." loop.  I can boot the machine into OS X with no problems.  No older kernels work for me.

Comment: Also @timmy, I don't think this bug is being worked on.  Those entries seem to have been closed following upstream kernel changes.  The bug entries I think you meant to link to are from several years ago; this is a new occurrence of the same bug.