# Unable to boot following update to Trusty, get "NMI handler taking too long" mesage

Tags: boot

Following my updating to 14.04 I can no longer boot into the system. I see lots of white text on a black background most of it makes no sense to me but I see "NMI handler took too long to run" and also "Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu1" Can anybody please help to restore the system to normality. Thnks in anticipation.

Comment: Can anyone answer this question?  I have a similar problem and tried to do a complete reinstall from liveCD.  Not possible, I get a "soft lockup" error.

Comment: I experience the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is related to not clearing the control debug register.

> CF140 Performance Monitoring IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_STATUS.
>
> CondChgd Bit Not
> Cleared by Reset
>
> Problem: The IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_STATUS MSR (38EH)
> should be cleared by reset. Due to this erratum, CondChgd (bit 63) of
> the IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_STATUS MSR may not be cleared.
>
> Implication: When
> this erratum occurs, performance monitoring software may behave
> unexpectedly. Errata Intel® Xeon® Processor E7 v2 Product Family 53
> Specification Update March 2015
>
> Workaround: It is possible for the
> BIOS to contain a workaround for this erratum

There is probably a [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1416414) for this included in kernels higher than  Ubuntu-3.13.0-35.61.

This may happen also if you are debugging SMP kernel using kgdb over serial port (over ethernet as well - probably in any configuration) with all CPU's online. I have to disable all CPUs but one if I want to debug smoothly, otherwise it works sometimes and sometimes not.